# RegEx - expression for ${value}

Tags: java, regex

Problem is simple I need to found all values in `${value}` for example for such text:

```
*test text $(1123) test texttest text${asd} test text test text test text ${123} test text[123132] test text [1231231]*
```

I should get

- `asd`
- `123`

I have done something like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/yQ0rP9/1) but as you can see it don't work good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
\$\{([^}]+)\}
```

you places `)` instead of `}` in negation of character class `([^}])`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yQ0rP9/2)

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use look behind to get the desired result:

Explore more

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Regex `(?<=\$\{)[^}]+` explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \$                       '$'
    \{                       '{'
  )                        end of look-behind
  [^}]+                    any character except: '}' (1 or more times)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG5aO0/1)

sample code:

```
String str = "test text $(1123) test texttest text${asd} test text test text test text ${123} test text[123132] test text [1231231]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$\\{)[^}]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

output:

```
asd
123
```

Comment: I thought you died =)